# Editing files contained in iPad app directly from PC without jailbreaking the iPad

Tags: ipad, file, edit

I have some CSS in my hybrid iPad app files that I would like to edit. I came across iFunBox and iExplore, which allows me to move the file between iOS and macOS. But I cannot edit the files directly. I am doing the following:

1. Open and Edit the file in TextWrangler by clicking on the file in iFunBox UI
2. Reveal the file in finder
3. Copy the file to iPad by dragging it to iFunbox

It appears that it should be easy iFunBox or similar to automate this process and hance make the file editable directly.

Anyone aware of an app which achieves this?

Attached is a screenshot of my cluttered Desktop, showing the iExplore, TextWrangler and Finder window. Ideally, I would like to see an Edit option alongwith Open and Quick Look options.

[image]

Comment: Definitely not programming related

Answer (score 0):

Wait, do you just want to be able to edit files via FTP? If so use, [Gusto](http://horseandtherook.com/gusto/)

Comment: I am developing iPad app which has some UIWebViews. The local HTML content for these webviews come from a local js file, which I need to edit. Gusto seems to be an editor in iPad, with an embedded FTP client. I doubt if it can access the files of other apps installed on the iPad.Please correct me if I am wrong (its a paid app, so I cant try). I have updated my post for more on what I want. Thanks so much.

Comment: Not that its a fix but while developing try serving the `js` file directly off your local mac file system. Beats copying each time you make a change